# xmlInternalTreeParse gives "failed to load HTTP resource" but URL loads in browser

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

Given two URLs:

```
iris <- "http://service.iris.edu/fdsnws/event/1/query?starttime=2010-04-04&endtime=2010-04-05"
caltech <- "http://service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/event/1/query?starttime=2010-04-04&endtime=2010-04-05"
```

Running

```
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(iris)
```

works, but

```
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(caltech)
```

returns

```
Error: 1: failed to load HTTP resource
```

despite the fact that both work fine in my browser.  Furthermore, checking the status using the httr package gives "200", e. g.:

```
> GET(caltech)$status_code
[1] 200
>
```

What is going on here?  This is causing issues with my rFDSN package on CRAN, so I'd really appreciate some guidance!

Comment: that caltech site (which is missing quotes) is returning 503 errors (in browser and in R) on a regular basis. your pkg shld be looking for status codes and presenting warnings to the user on HTTP errors.

Comment: Yes,  I noticed those occasional errors, however even when it gave a status of 200 consistently, the xml parser would still fail for cal tech.  Is it somehow "more sensitive" (less tolerant of latency, or something)?

Comment: They are far from occasional (I keep getting it whether on our dedicated scraping internet hosts—I work for Project Sonar—or on comcast). Until I can get a successful return from the site, I won't be able to debug further.

Comment: I will contact the sysadmin to find out what's going on, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the following to work pretty consistently:

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)
library(XML)

UA <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36"
res <- GET("http://service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/event/1/query",
           query=list(starttime="2010-04-04", endtime="2010-04-05"),
           user_agent(UA), verbose())

x_doc <- read_xml(content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8"))
ns <- xml_ns_rename(xml_ns(x_doc), d1="def")
xml_find_all(x_doc, ".//def:event", ns)
## {xml_nodeset (118)}
##  [1] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
##  [2] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
##  [3] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
##  [4] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
##  [5] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
##  [6] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
##  [7] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
##  [8] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
##  [9] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
## [10] <event publicID="quakeml:service.scedc.caltech.edu/fdsnws/even ...
## ...
```

You can remove the `verbose()` in production. Strangely enough, the user agent may be making a difference, but I can get it to work without it (though that site errors more when it's not present).

Note:

```
res$times
##      redirect    namelookup       connect   pretransfer starttransfer         total 
##      0.000000      0.001938      0.158912      0.159512     13.198304     13.629542
```

is also fairly consistent (~15s per request). You may want to force a 30+s timeout with `httr::timeout()` (add it to the params for `GET()`).

I know you're using the `XML` package, but you also probably know the namespace dance there and:

```
X_doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

works equally as well (and consistently) as the `read_xml()` call.